# USB Mouse and Keyboard not working in Linux 4 Tegra

Tags: ubuntu, keyboard, mouse, nvidia, arm

I'm new to Tegra Linux development. I have a Tamontem NG Evaluation board with the Tegra 3 Chip. I installed L4T sample file system from NVIDIA Tegra resources (https://developer.nvidia.com/linux-tegra) and installed the file system as described in the documentation provided in NVIDIA site.

Already there was an SD card with L4T running. I don't want to change the boot loader. So I copied the `boot.scr.uimg` to root (/) folder and `uImage` to boot (`/boot`) and it starts booting from the existing SD card. After that while booting, some errors occurred in some Bluetooth devices (there is no Bluetooth device in the board). So I disabled Bluetooth by giving the following command:

```
sudo mv /etc/init/bluetooth.conf /etc/init/bluetooth.conf.noexec
```

Now the problem is that mouse and keyboard are not working. So I can't login. Even though I installed desktop, the mouse and keyboard are not working. But mouse and keyboard are enumerating. The `lsusb` command is showing the USB mouse and keyboard.

- The installed file system is Ubuntu 13.04
- Linux Kernel version is 3.1

What to do?

Comment: I think the problem is with kernel. The kernel in the uImage and the rootfs are in mismatch. uImage kernel doesn't have USB mouse and keyboard support